# C# Sockets - Recognize same computer

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm doing a software which includes Udp and Tcp sockets server-client. I want that only if the client is connected to the TCP server, the Udp will respond to it. I know how to do that, but I have a problem - if someone will use two different computers on the same LAN, the external IP will be the same and I will have problem checking the tcp/udp connection because of that.
So I tought at first that when the client connects to my server, he will send his internal IP and i'll use it to check if it's really one computer or more.

But I don't know if there an easier way, because that one is pretty complicated. Any ideas?

Comment: No need from "send internal IP". For TCP connections this is made by NAT. Two connections are to the same external IP, but NAT remembers that one is connected to internal IP "A" and other with "B".

Comment: Nice, I did not know that, and good post.

Comment: If you need also a UDP connection through NAT than search for [UDP hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching)

Comment: @i486 Thanks :) but in my check i'll be checking the external address to see if they are multiple connections from the same network, I need to compare TCP ip to the UDP ip and see if there is a match, if so - the udp server will handle the user because he's connected to the TCP. So... I need to somehow change to check?

Comment: but connection isn't IP only... you got different Ports don't you?

Comment: @Sag1v, Yea of course - I'll give an example:
Let's say there is PC1 that is connecting to my tcp server through ip: 123.123.123.123:12, and to my udp server through 123.123.123.123:15. I need to see if they are both the same computer and are made through my software in order to let my server handle them. So... Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Assign an ID to each connection and make the UDP packets include that ID. Match on ID, not on "internal IP". There is no good definition for internal IP. A computer can have dozens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign an ID to each connection and make the UDP packets include that ID. Match on ID, not on "internal IP".

There is no good definition for internal IP. A computer can have dozens.